# dynamic subdomains in Symfony 1.4

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony1, subdomain, symfony-1.4

I am trying to create dynamic subdomains in .htaccess.
I want something like this:

```
http://ladygaga.koncert.com  --> http://koncert.com/concerts/ladygaga
```

Comment: You might want to consider formulating an actual question in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kris wallsmith published something in the symfony blog, about subdomain routing in sf1.2. maybe this helps you: http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-adding-subdomain-requirements-to-routing-yml