# symfony : application mobile on server on line

Tags: apache, symfony-1.4

I have a very simple question,I created my site unsing symfony 1.4,I also created three applications :

- apps/frontend  ==> exampel.com
- apps/backend ==> example.com/backend.php
- apps/mobile ==> mobile.example.com

for frontend and backend works fine on line server but for mobile version I created a subdomain(mobile.example.com) correctly but here is my problem.

How I configure symfony or server on line to access directly to mobile application when I browse the link mobile.exemple.com?

I mean I have all project in example.com folder not in subdomain(mobile.exemple.com) folder.

Any Idea?

Edit :

I hope subdomain for different applications not for different modules in one applicatoion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a good solution and simple than using sfRequestRoute configuration,finally for me :

I change subdomain for different symfony applications and just to have one index.php controlling your project.

```
<?php


 require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');


 switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) { 

case 'm.example.com': $configuration =    ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration( 'mobile', 'prod', false); break;

 case 'backend.example.com'.....

default: $configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration( 'frontend', 'prod', false); break; 

}

sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

and It's done.

Comment: This is a solution I have seen in a project I supported once. If it works for you then you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The link to [symfony blog](http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-adding-subdomain-requirements-to-routing-yml) from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678103/dynamic-subdomains-in-symfony-1-4) shows that you can use sfRequestRoute configuration for this.

Comment: I use sfRequestRoute in my mobile application but it dosn't work for me?

Comment: I hope subdomain for different application not for different modules in one applicatoion!

Comment: If you are entering into the *mobile* application from within the same *project* and your webserver knows how to serve you, Then your requests are being served through index.php, so that could be the place to start looking for the best configuration settings.

Comment: Really I can't get you without some code,the application will start with index.php that mean "fronend application",I tried to redirect it to "mobile application" using htaccess that dosn't work,I mean you explain a little your point...

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot understand you better. Toward the end of the symfony blog post linked here, the example goes into implementing subdomains for different applications (ie. frontend, backend, mobile) in one project. I do not have this yet in my projects, so I do not have more of an example, but that looks like the answer. I wish I could be more help to you.